# Starting node_exporter while disable-ling a specific collector - collector.diskstats

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

Since my servers are hosted in a VPS, I don't have a /proc/diskstats that can provide node_exporter (Version 0.17.0) with disk statistics. So I ended up with repetitive error messages :

ERRO[0037] ERROR: diskstats collector failed after 0.000034s: couldn't get diskstats: open /proc/diskstats: no such file or directory  source="collector.go:132"

I want to tell the exporter to ignore diskstats collector but was unable to do it. as just putting the flag --collector.diskstats does nothing as it is enabled by default.

how can I start the exporter while telling it to ignore the collector.diskstats (or any other collector) ?

Thank you so much !

Answer (score 9):

Try running

```
node_exporter --no-collector.diskstats
```

to disable the `diskstats` collector. The node_exporter [README](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter/blob/master/README.md#collectors) has more details about how to enable and disable particular collectors.

Comment: Glad to hear. Please upvote/mark as answered if this helped you.

Comment: I did Oliver. however as my reputation is still low, it says that my rank was recorded but still not publicly visible :(

Comment: It's a shame that prefixing with `--no-` isn't documented in the `--help` option.